# React Native Set A Part Of State Update Whole View

Tags: react-native, view, state

I need to print dates as accordion that containt many times inside,

I saved the whole date and time on one state of array, i loop my dates using collapsible like this:

```
<Collapsible collapsed={ this.state.date_tab !== date_index }>
    { this._renderTimes( date_index ) }
</Collapsible>
```

the `date_tab` used as selected accordion, so there's only one active collapsible allowed.

When i change the `date_tab` state, the whole dates and content rerender it's view so, it's make my collapsible slow to open caused all view rerender from begining.

**Is there a way to close the activated collapsible, then open the pressed collapsible without rerender the other collapsible?**

I tried using array, but not work, when i set state the array, it still rerender all view

Answer (score 0):

Move collapsible and renderTimes to a separate component. Make the component a [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent). Supply collapsed prop and times array to the collapsible component.

PureComponent will render only if the props are different. So, only two of the collapsible components will render, and not all of them.